# Cannot broadcast the table over X rows: X rows

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a broadcast join, but I am getting the error below:
`Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table over 357913941 rows: 480202810 rows.` 
This is where is set the max number of rows in the spark source code:

- [step_1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L122)
- [step_2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L217)
- [step_3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/unsafe/map/BytesToBytesMap.java#L99)

Code below:

```py
right_df = right_df.withColumn("new_col", F.to_timestamp("date") + F.expr("INTERVAL 30 minutes")*F.col('period'))

join_condition = [right_df.col_0 == left_df.col_0, 
                  right_df.col_1 == left_df.col_1, 
                  right_df.col_2 == left_df.col_2,
                  right_df.col_3 == left_df.col_3,
                  right_df.time_point.between(left_df.interval_start, left_df.interval_end)]

df = left_df.join(F.broadcast(right_df), on=join_condition, how='left')
```

My `right_df` dataframe is only **1,7GB** which is smaller than the limit [8GB](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26075).
I have set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to 8GB:

```py
value = 8*10**9
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", f'{value}')
```

Set up: Databricks Runtime Version 7.5 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: Can you post your transformation code? You might be using right_df multiple times (implicitly) by previous transformation.

Comment: @YosiDahari I just updated my code regarding your comment.

Comment: So looks like there is a hard stop limitation on Spark code `(BytesToBytesMap.MAX_CAPACITY / 1.5)` and it recommends the number of rows `should not be over 341 million`. It's no longer about the size, it's the number of records limitation. What are you expecting?